Parametrized random variables with implicitly defined parameter
As a follow up to my previous question  Almost sure convergence of random variables; dependence on $\omega$, I have the following question. In particular, I would like to say that I have a parametrized sequence of iid random variables $X_i(\omega;\alpha)$ for which $\alpha\mapsto X_i(\omega;\alpha)$ is monotone increasing and$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega;\alpha)-\mu\cdot \alpha\right|=0\qquad\qquad (*)
$$almost surely. I would like to use the above to say that if for each $n$, $\alpha_n$ (which depends on the draw $\omega$) is chosen so that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega;\alpha_n)=C$, I would like to say that $\alpha_n$ is $\omega$-almost surely bounded uniformly in $n$.
My (incorrect) idea would be to say by the convergence of $(*)$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n$ for which$$
(**)\qquad\left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\left(\omega;\frac{(C+\delta)}{\mu}\right)- (C+\delta)\right|<\varepsilon\implies C+\delta-\varepsilon<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\left(\omega;\frac{(C+\delta)}{\mu}\right).
$$Thus if $\varepsilon<\delta/2$ we clearly have$$
C+\delta/2<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\left(\omega;\frac{(C+\delta)}{\mu}\right).
$$However, since $\alpha\mapsto X_i(\omega;\alpha)$ is monotone increasing and we wish it to be exactly equal to $C$, this implies that $\alpha<(C+\delta)/\mu$.
My argument falls apart however when I make the statement $(**)$ since the $n$ I get will depend on the draw $\omega$. I can however say that for every $\eta>0$, and fixed $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n$ for which $$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\left(\omega;\frac{(C+\delta)}{\mu}\right)- (C+\delta)\right|<\varepsilon\right)>1-\eta,
$$However, I am not clear how to upgrade this to the desired almost sure boundedness. Any help would be appreciated.
